# Using CSS only, is it possible to make a UL list have no bullet when it has only one item?

Tags: css

Is it possible to use CSS only, to have a solution that works even on IE8, that

1. when a `<ul>` list has 2 or more items, then keep the bullets in front of the items as usual.
2. when there is only 1 item, then don't show the bullet, because it can be strange that a single item has a bullet in front of it.

An example is shown on  http://jsfiddle.net/SzQL6/37/

```
<input id="an-input">
<ul id="the-list">
    <li>error msg 1</li>
    <li>error msg 2</li>
</ul>
```

(The error messages should be left-aligned with the left edge of the input box above the error messages, when there are bullets and when there is no bullet.)

Using JavaScript, I could do it: http://jsfiddle.net/SzQL6/40/

But can this be done by CSS only (and that it can work on IE8)?

Comment: css alone doesn't have conditional statements (that apply to dom conditions I mean). you can apply a class to those items specifically in html and write a separate declaration in css for that class but I'm sure you know of that

Comment: you mean using class and JavaScript?

Comment: You can use `#the-list li:first-child:last-child { display: block; }`, but sadly `:last-child` is not supported until IE9...

Comment: no js. I mean you control the markup, so if the list only has one item you can add an html class to the ul when you write the markup. like `<ul class="single">` - otherwise, as stated by guffa, the options you have for modern browsers will not work with crippled versions of IE.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it with CSS only, though it is only compatible with CSS3 (which anybody with a updated browser will have, or as Guffa pointed out, IE >= 9), by using the `:only-child` pseudo-class selector:

```
.error-list { list-style-position: inside; margin-top: 0; color: #f77 }
.error-list li:only-child { list-style-type: none; }
```

The rule is being applied to any `li` element that is the only child of its parent (`.error-list`).
According to MDN:

> The `:only-child` CSS pseudo-class represents any element which is the only child of its parent. This is the same as `:first-child:last-child` or `:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1)`, but with a lower specificity.

See the example on this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SzQL6/41/

Comment: The `:only-child` pseudo class is not supported until IE 9.

Comment: "which anybody with a **updated** browser will have" I guess that doesn't include any IE except 11. Will edit the answer, though.

Comment: Ah, beat me to it.. I had made this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SzQL6/42/). +1 Kudos

Comment: @LaughDonor Let the fastest keyboard win!

Comment: “CSS3 (which anybody with a updated browser will have, – –)” is seriously misleading. CSS3 is just a vague collective name for specs and drafts at very different levels of maturity; much of “CSS3” has no browser support.

Comment: in the answer, IE > 9, meaning IE 10+ ?

Comment: @動靜能量 Mistype indeed, I meant it to be "IE >= 9", which would be IE 9+